# When to use conjunction and when not?

Tags: conjunctions

I'm reading a book and I see that in one of the sentence it doesn't use in conjunction "**that**". Therefore I'm a little confused about this topic- where I need to put conjunction and where not.

> I'm afraid your luggage is ten kilos overweight; you will have to pay
>   extra.

Before I saw it I would write it as follow:

> I'm afraid **that** your luggage is ten kilos overweight; you will have to pay
>   extra.

[image]

Comment: Inserting images of scanned text is discouraged since is it not searchable. It would be far better if you changed it to typed text.

Comment: I put both as you an see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [that-clause](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses) can be used in several ways.

> I think **that** he is lying - *following a [verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-that-clause)*
>
> I am sure **that** he is lying - *following an adjective*
>
> I know the reason **that** he is lying - *following a noun*

In all of these cases, the **that** can be omitted. It is much more likely to be omitted in spoken English than in written English. Uneducated people are more likely to omit it than educated people. In spoken English,

- it is usually omitted after a verb
- it is frequently omitted after an adjective
- it is occasionally omitted after a noun.

Comment: I wouldn't say the speaker or the author of the example sentence is uneducated at all. E.g. "I'm afraid your luggage..." sounds perfectly correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I did not say that omitting **that** in the OP's sentence was incorrect. I did not say that the speaker or the author of the sentence was uneducated.

Comment: `Uneducated people are more likely to omit it than educated people` which *implies* it is common, and uneducated, to omit "that" in sentences. Can you support your statement that uneducated people are more likely not to utter "that" than educated people?

Comment: @Mari-LouA:  I have no intention of trying to support a statement **that** I did not make.

Comment: @JavaLatte who did, then?

Comment: This answer doesn't mention when the word "that" is required.  It is optional when the "that" merely *introduces* the clause, as in "[that] your luggage is ten kilos overweight".  It is optional when it represents the *object* of the subordinate clause, as in "an answer [that] I understand".  It is required when it represents the *subject* of the subordinate clause, as in "a question *that* is useful".

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan: the question specifically refers to the usage of **that** as a conjunction (introducing a clause). The other possiblilities that you mentioned are usages of **that** as a relative pronoun. Omission of relative pronouns is covered in this link: http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm

Comment: @DanGetz: Compare Mari-Lou A's version of the statement:  "uneducated people are more likely not to utter "that" than educated people" with my statement "Uneducated people are more likely to omit it than educated people". Note the usage of **utter** in Mari-Lou A's version. As I made clear, "It is much more likely to be omitted in spoken English". and  "In spoken English, it is **usually** omitted after a verb".

Comment: @JavaLatte right, but can you support your statement, which she is clearly referring to?

Comment: @DanGetz, of course I can't. But if anybody ever did a study relating to people who omit **that** from **that**-clauses in writing and people who write **alot** (sic)  and people who write "I wish I **was**...", I would put money on a strong correlation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what the general rules are. I agree with the other answer that in many cases you can either use *that* or leave it out, and it doesn't change the meaning or grammaticality. But I think I can help answer for the example you gave. I think it is somewhat of a special case. The phrase "I'm afraid [that]" has two different meanings:

1. **I feel fear** that it could be the case, but do not know if it is or not
2. **Unfortunately**, it is the case that

In your example sentence, it's clearly the second meaning, because the speaker knows it to be true. They're expressing their *regret*, not fear.

Each of these meanings can be expressed both with or without the word *that*, but I think the word *that* is used more often with the first meaning than with the second. That is, if you want to say:

> Unfortunately, your luggage is overweight.

It is more common to say:

> I'm afraid your luggage is overweight.

You *can* say it like:

> I'm afraid **that** your luggage is overweight.

But when I see or hear that, I'm likely to think of the first meaning, where the speaker is unsure and feels fear.

Comment: Good point. I have just done a quick search on Google books for 'afraid that' and I can confirm that it's predominantly (by about 10 to 1) fear rather than regret. This is specific to **afraid**, though, and the OP is asking about omission of **that** in general.

Comment: @JavaLatte right, I wasn't trying to give a full answer to the question. Just wanted to add information about the situation given in the question. I'll try to edit to make that clear.